# PL/SQL Cursors - Retrieving data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus, database-cursor

I need to input a product code as a parameter that will retrieve said product and other information. I require more info than I have provided, I've started small scale to attempt to debug any errors early, but I cannot see why the code below doesn't work. I'm using SQLPlus, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE product_info(PRODUCT_NO IN CHAR)
AS
    v_product PRODUCTS%ROWTYPE;
    v_suborders  SUBORDERS.ORDER_NO%TYPE;

    CURSOR cur_products IS
    SELECT p.name, p.prod_id, p.description, p.unit_price, s.order_no
    FROM PRODUCTS P, SUBORDERS S
    WHERE p.prod_id = product_no;

BEGIN
OPEN cur_products;
LOOP
FETCH cur_products INTO v_product, v_suborders;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Code: ' || v_product.prod_id 
  || ' Name: ' || v_product.name 
  || ' Description: ' || v_product.description
  || ' Price: ' || v_product.unit_price
  || ' Order: ' || v_suborders);
END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product number does not exist'); 
WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Operation failed  ' || 'SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE); 
ROLLBACK;
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we fetch into a variable its structure must match the projection of the query we're fetching. Or if we're fetching into multiple variables we need one variable per column in the projection. Your code doesn't do either.

The simplest solution is to use your cursor to define the variable, like this:

```
    CURSOR cur_products IS
        SELECT p.name, p.prod_id, p.description, p.unit_price, s.order_no
        FROM PRODUCTS P, SUBORDERS S
        WHERE p.prod_id = product_no;
    v_rec  cur_products%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    OPEN cur_products;
    LOOP
    FETCH cur_products INTO v_rec;
    ...
```

An alternate solution is to use an implicit cursor. You could rewrite your code like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE product_info(PRODUCT_NO IN CHAR)
AS
BEGIN
    for v_rec in (SELECT p.name, p.prod_id, p.description, p.unit_price, s.order_no
                  FROM PRODUCTS P, SUBORDERS S
                  WHERE p.prod_id = product_no )
    LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Code: ' || v_rec.prod_id 
      || ' Name: ' || v_rec.name 
      || ' Description: ' || v_rec.description
      || ' Price: ' || v_rec.unit_price
      || ' Order: ' || v_rec.odrer_no);
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Product number does not exist'); 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Operation failed  ' || 'SQLCODE: ' || SQLCODE); 
    ROLLBACK;
END; 
/
```

---

Incidentally, you query doesn't have a join between PRODUCTS and SUBORDERS so your result set will be a product (cross-join) or all the records in both tables. Almost certainly you don't want that.

Also, it is bad practice not to re-raise an exception in the exception handler (apart from some edge cases). It doesn't matter in a piece of toy code like this, but don't fall into bad habits.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but please update it to use %ROWTYPE instead of %TYPE in the first solution.